# how to get the files of assest subfolder in android?

Tags: android, android-assets

How can i get the files of assets sub folder.in my Assets folder i have another sub folder(sample).I want to get all files of sample folder and store it into sdcard.Please can any one help me?

Thanking in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way..

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] files = assetManager.list("sample");
for(String filename : files) {
.....
}
```